# ElasticSearch to populate multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use ES to index logs coming from different processes.
Assume I have 2 sources: `ServerA` and `ServerB` Logs from the processes are formatted in json. 
Example log:

```
{
  "level": "DEBUG",
  "logger": "REPOSITORY",
  "timestamp": 1405982400689,
  "attrs": {
    "profile": "ServerA",
    "organization": "FOOBAR"
  },
  "thread": "main",
  "message": "Repository.store() : Stored successfully in /central/zone/cef9cccab964"
}
```

How can I get ES to update multiple indexes when it sees a new document ? In this case I want indices on the profile and organization values.
Do I have to

1. Create indexes using the ES REST api before ES sees any logs.
2. Supply an `_index` field to each json document
3. Have multiple values in the `_index` field to indicate what indexes must be updated ? 
   i.e should I have:

   **"_index": {"ServerA" , "FOOBAR"}**

Please let me know if this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Not clear what you want here. Are you creating separate indexes for each server or each organization, or a combination of the two? And if so, why? What are you gaining from that approach?

Comment: I second John, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. But a quick answer is that you *can't* get ES to update multiple indexes for a single document. A document is indexed only in a single index. So you need to rethink this.

Comment: Thanks John and Rotem. I want to be able to support queries on the logs from the 2 sources. The queries will be based on the "profile" and "organization" field. **Example: Show me all logs matching %pattern% for profile="ServerA" and organization="FOOBAR" . ** So I assumed that I should create 2 indexes, one for each field. But on more reading, it seems ES indexes are different from a traditional DB index. So should I instead be creating one index and use types to distinguish the data ?